Qbits vs RSA vs Time
So I'm writing a section for my Rats of NIMH fanfiction where the Rat Republic using Quantum computers to wreck havoc on the US economy for the war effort.
Well, the issue is that I like to pretend to be realistic in my fanfiction. So said quantum computer is crammed into a nuclear ocean liner and moored off the coast of Iran for safe keeping.
Granted I will be nudging things a little for artistic liberty, so the sentient rats are getting an upper hand.
But how many Qbits would it take to crack public RSA 2048 keys in ~2-3 month's worth of time? Or alternatively, how many Qbits could be powered off of 80kW? (I'm guessing a handful at best.)


how many Qbits could be powered off of 80kW?

Actually, the Qbits themselves use hardly any power.
On the other hand, they are quite shy, and to decohere if you look at them funny [1].  If a large amount of power is used, it's used to do the extreme isolation that Qbits need from their environment, such as cooling to 20mK (that is, real cold) temperatures.  Whether that is needed (and how much) would depend on the Qbit physical implementation; some (such as superconducting qbits) need that sort of them; others (such as ion trap or photonic-based qubits) don't need that nearly as much...
Hence, you could plausibly [2] make up any answer you want...
[1]: That is, if looking at them involves measuring them...
[2]: Or at least, at least as plausibly as sapient rats

I am aware about the cooling thing, that is where almost all of the power gets consumed. But I suspect the more qbits=bigger wafer=more energy needed to cool the thing down to almost absolute zero.

"Or at least, at least as plausibly as sapient rats" I like your thinking lol.

@qwertykeyboard: "more energy needed to cool the thing down to almost absolute zero" - unless you use an implementation of qubits that doesn't require drastic cooling (e.g. trapped ion, photonic, nitrogen vacancy (n.v. needs cooling, but not nearly as much)).  As an author, you get to pick...

Granted, I have this sort of "JIT" manner of writing, brainstorming specific parts during my walks. You are right though, I should of done more reading! I didn't even know that quantum gates are a thing. It's like asking how many bits are required to run Minecraft! How embarrassing.

An estimate for RSA 2048 is 20 million Qbits/8 hours.
By doing some EXTREMELY questionable math, that would be about 4 to 5 months with only 1000 Qbits.
Assuming the rats pull some industrial espionage, collaboration with the Russians and Chinese, R&D development funded by war money (First Quantum ASIC's anyone?), and chea- ugh... I mean... Artistic liberty! Uh, yeah! Artistic liberty! Totally not cheating.
So that would be about 9 to 12 keys cracked over four years. Ngl, I was expecting a LITTLE more: 1 key per 3 months, but with a careful selection, you could wreck absolute HAVOC on something like the home video game console market, or the prepaid android phone market. (Ever tried rooting a tracfone?)
That, coupled with stealing private keys, would cause a good chunk of economic damage. Total war BABYYY!!!

How did you get to this value of 1000 qubits? And I presume those are stable, logical qubits?

"Qbits/hour" Like I said, horribly inaccurate math! And yes, those are logical qbits.

It's fine to use some fiction in your book, but this is a Q/A site on cryptography. We don't allow this kind of artistic liberty.
